# Pandas best practices - using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some tutorial and I have a DataFrame with some different columns.

I have prepared the group object:

```
country_grp = df.groupby(['Country'])
```

Which one is better to use?

1. `country_grp['Some Column Name'].value_counts().loc['United States']`
   or
2. `country_grp.get_group('United States')['Some Column Name'].value_counts()`

Something else?

Comment: Try to timeit to have a first idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use `groupby` for a single group, but `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Country'].eq('United States'), 'Some Column Name'].value_counts()
```

`groupby` adds an overhead of collecting the groups, sorting them (optional but default)… there is no reason to do that if you plan to use a single group.

That said, among your two options, the second one is still more efficient than the first as you compute the `value_counts` only for one group, while you compute for all in the first one only to discard all but "United States".